# can i make a view visible to some specific users and other not on Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I want to make some pages not accessible for some users , what i mean for example i want to make user1 can see a viewa and can not see a viewb, I have tried to do that I have developed 2 functions of permissions and role user function:

Here is the code of the 2 functions of permissions in views.py:

```
def is_normaluser_login_required(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        user=request.user  
        if not user.roleuser.is_normaluser:
            return render(request, 'unauthorized.html') # or raise 403
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper

def is_privilgeuser_login_required(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        user=request.user  
        if not user.roleuser.is_privilgeuser:
            return render(request, 'unauthorized.html')  # or raise 403
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

then i have go to home template where there was a sidebar contain 2 list(every list call a view) , I want to make just the users that are permitted to see this form-list on the navigate bar;

Here is the code in template.html that contain the 2 forms that i want limit the access for both of them:

```
<nav class="mt-2">
    <ul class="nav" >
      {% if perms.app1_name.is_normaluser_login_required %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{%url 'form_module1'%}" class="nav-link">
            </a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if perms.app1_name.is_privilgeuser_login_required %}
      <!---->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{%url 'form_module2'%}" class="nav-link">
            </a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

---> after that the two lists disappear from the navigate bar (like it doesn't matter if the user have his role or not) otherwise i have mentioned from the admin page the users and their role.

it's like those :

```
  {% if perms.app_name.is_privilgeuser_login_required %}
      #code...
  {% endif %}
```

->not workful

I do not if this can be applicable , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use decorators in template like that you can create custom [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904784/reuse-the-decorator-of-a-view-from-a-template) or [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#how-to-create-custom-template-tags-and-filters).

Instead of creating custom filter/tags you can do this by request. 
Change your code like this this

```
<nav class="mt-2">
    <ul class="nav" >
      {% if user.roleuser.is_normaluser %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{%url 'form_module1'%}" class="nav-link">
            </a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if user.roleuser.is_privilgeuser %}
      <!---->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{%url 'form_module2'%}" class="nav-link">
            </a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
```