# Decorator to set any number of attributes of callable

Tags: python, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I need a Python decorator to add any number of named attributes to the decorated callable.

For example:

```py
@attributes(foo='this', bar='exactly')  # <-- Implement this decorator!
def fun1(i):
   return i * 2

assert fun1.foo == 'this'
assert fun1.bar == 'exactly'
```

There exists a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15794419/), the answers to which deal with setting a single attribute with a fixed name. It doesn't apply here for setting an arbitrary number of attributes.

This doesn't work:

```py
def attributes(**kwargs):
    def _inner(func):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            func.k = v
        return func
    return _inner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that implements the decorator:

```py
def attributes(**kwargs):
    def _inner(func):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(func, k, v)
        return func
    return _inner
```

Alternatively, here is a class that implements the decorator:

```py
class attributes:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, func):
        for k, v in self.kwargs.items():
            setattr(func, k, v)
        return func
```

Answer (score -1):

`func.k = v` sets `foo.k`, not `foo.foo` or `foo.bar`. To set an attribute with a dynamic name, use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) instead:

```
setattr(func, k, v)
```